# C++ : Pass an object as argument

Tags: c++, class, object

I'm just wondering why this code doesn't compile :

```
#include <iostream>

class Player
{
    public:
        Player()
        {

        }
};

class Game
{
    public:
        Game()
        {

        }

        void getPlayer(Player &player)
        {

        }
};

int main()
{
    Game *game = new Game();
    Player *player = new Player();

    game->getPlayer(&player);

    return 0;
}
```

I would like to pass the player object as an argument to the method getPlayer() of the Game class.

Regards

Comment: what is the error message? usually it will tell you what is wrong

Comment: `player` is a `Player*`, so when you pass `&player`, that is type `Player**`.  That can't bind to `Player&`.

Comment: Why are you using `new` for this ?  Put your objects on the stack and pass by reference as needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your method:

```
void getPlayer(Player &player)
```

accepts an lvalue reference to object of type `Player` but you are trying to pass `Player **` to it, to fix compilation error just dereference your pointer:

```
game->getPlayer(*player);
```

but design of your program does not look right (passing reference to a method that called `getPlayer` etc.)

Comment: Thanks a lot Slava ! Yes , indeed the design was fastly made because I'm currently writing a game with the SDL2. I had a problem with object reference so I decided to write a little file in order to see where the error could be fixed !